# cakephp date validation

Tags: validation, cakephp, date

In cakePHP how would you achieve date validation when placing your validation statement inside  the controller. could I put a second if statement after the first validation statement? i am not sure how you'd make it validate as systemdate is before or equal to the expiry date

```
if($this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('Relationship.partyone','Relationship.active'))))
{
  $this->Invoice->create(); 
 if ($this->Invoice->saveAll($this->request->data,array('validate'=>false))) 
 { 
  $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need custom validation for date date comparison

**In Model**

```
var $validate = array(
        'date' => array(
        'rule' => array('datevalidation', 'systemDate' ),
        'message' => 'Current Date and System Date is mismatched'
            )
        ); 

 function datevalidation( $field=array(), $compare_field=null ) 
    {
        if ($field['date'] > $compare_field)
        return TRUE;
        else return FALSE;
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
if($this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('Relationship.partyone','Relationship.active',Relationship.date))))
```

Comment: should be Relationship.datevalidation  but you sir are a champ!

Comment: umm, why not just do `return $field['date'] > $compare_field;`